# Getting value of children with same name - Firebase Swift3

Tags: swift, loops, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the following query to get the snapshot below.

```
dbRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: text).queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in })
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate over the values of the children "username" (i.e. bill, billy, billykins) because they all have the same key ("username"). I'm trying to extract all the names and put them in an array of names.

```
Snap (users) {
   fDrzmwRUt2guh3O8pc792ipyEqA3 =     {
       username = bill;
   };
   qyQkIOxSpXgQoUoh0QNvPlkQ1Mp1 =     {
       username = billy;
   };
   edSk54xSpXgQoYoh0QNvOlkQ1Mp3 =     {
       username = billykins;
   };
}
```

This is my function which gets the snapshot and tries to iterate over it. However, the loop crashes:

```
func findUsers(text: String) {
        print("search triggered")
        dbRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: text).queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)

        for i in snapshot.children{
            let value = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
            let username = value["username"]
            print(username)
            self.userList.append(username!)
            print(self.userList)
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print("searchUsers \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Here's a fraction of the log. Too long to post:

```
0x1002cg360 <+272>: adr    x9, #268929               ; "value type is not bridged to Objective-C"
0x1002cg364 <+276>: nop    
0x1002cg368 <+280>: str    x9, [x8, #8]
->  0x1002cg36c <+284>: brk    #0x1
0x1002cg370 <+288>: .long  0xffffffe8                ; unknown opcode
```

Comment: use orderby query on username

Comment: Did you try anything yet? The Firebase documentation is usually a decent starting point: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events. If you prefer a more hands-on approach, try the Firebase code lab for iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs

Comment: That's actually how I'm getting the snapshot. I just edited my question. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @DanielGrigsby You want all the user's name or just name start with `bill`?

Comment: @NiravD You're right. I only want names starting with "bill". But the result of my query is already only usernames starting with bill. That's what the .queryStarting(at: text) and .queryEnding(at: text) are for. My issue is that I need to extract only the names (bill, billy, billykins) from the snapshot.

Comment: @DanielGrigsbyCan you add console logs for your current code

Comment: This post had the answer I'm looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550056/get-data-out-of-array-of-firebase-snapshots?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I was looking for. I needed to loop through the big snapshot to extract the child snapshots into an array, and then loop through the child snapshots by value to get the usernames:

```
func findUsers(text: String) {
    print("search triggered")
    dbRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: text).queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found")
        } else {

            var blaArray = [FIRDataSnapshot]()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot //downcast
                blaArray.append(snap)
            }

            for child in blaArray {
                let dict = child.value as! NSDictionary
                let username = dict["username"]!
                print(username)

            }
    }) { (error) in
        print("searchUsers \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Adapted from this post: [Get data out of array of Firebase snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550056/get-data-out-of-array-of-firebase-snapshots?rq=1)