# How to unpack multiple levels of nested JSON in Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I would regularly have a JSON topic, for example `message`, then nested in that is a `random ID`, then the `message` text as a string inside the random ID. But, I need to decipher multiple levels of random IDs. Is that possible in Firebase for Swift? This is what I mean:

[image]

This is my code:

```
     Database.database().reference().child("app").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
         //app is first in the JSON tree
         let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

         let msg = dict["message"] as! String
```

Obviously this is crashing the app, as it's looking for "Message" in the first RandomID. Is there a solution to this? I haven't found resources for specifically what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to loop over the children of `snapshot` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

```
Database.database().reference().child("app").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot //downcast

        let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let msg = dict["message"] as! String
    }
})
```

Also see:

- [Get data out of array of Firebase snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550056/get-data-out-of-array-of-firebase-snapshots?rq=1)
- [Swift Firebase -How to get all the k/v when using queryOrdered(byChild: ).queryEqual(toValue: )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319415/swift-firebase-how-to-get-all-the-k-v-when-using-queryorderedbychild-querye/55319514#55319514)
- other [questions about looping over child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+loop+over+children)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. One note: FIRDataSnapshot is now DataSnapshot.

Comment: Woops... good point, thanks for flagging. I knew that, and still forgot to modify the copy/pasted code. I updated the code in my answer for future finders.